# SQL table questions

Tags: sql, qsqlquery

Given the SQL tables "cars" and "drivers", where both have an id field as the primary key, and "drivers" has an id associating them to a car, how would you write a SQL query to show which drivers are paired with which cars?

Sorry for the beginner level question, just trying to learn this new language. TIA

Comment: Hint: `JOIN`...

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple `JOIN` (aka "inner join"). Making a few assumptions about the columns names, your query should look like:

```
select
  d.*,
  c.*
from cars c
join drivers d on d.car_id = c.id
```